# c++ while loop error strange behavior

Tags: c++

I have a while loop that's essentially doing a binary search.  It's for searching for dates in a huge file and exhibiting some strange behavior.  It was printing out the wrong index everytime and after debugging it for 10 minutes I put in a cout statement "what is the going on" at the very beginning of the loop

```
while(left < right){
    cout<<"what is going on"<<endl; 

    bunch of other stuff
}
```

When I ran this it worked all of a sudden. I uncommented it and it broke again.  So it's as if the loop doesn't execute without the cout.  I have never encountered anything like this does anyone know of a reason that might be causing this? I'm on xcode.

This file has about 2million rows but there's no speed issue it seems, when I uncomment that line it finds the right date fairly fast

Comment: That is really not enough information to the answer the question. The only time I have encountered something like this is when I had multiple threads and printing something out just happened to stall the program long enough that the information was available.

Comment: It's impossible to predict what the problem might be from pseudo-code.

Comment: From the information provided, the only possible answer is: ***You have a bug in your program.*** (*It might be an uninitialized variable, but it is impossible to know because there is not enough information in the question.*)

Comment: This is called a *Heisenbug*. You could try using valgrind or equivalent to find buffer overflows in your code. Failing that you'll have to divide-and-conquer. Try to produce a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will either discover the bug in the process of generating an MCVE, or be able to get a good answer by posting the MCVE.

Comment: I understand its hard to debug or understand without pseudocode but does the notion that a cout<< statement could affect execution of a loop make any sense?

Comment: Are you using the array offset, since arrays start at 0, not 1?

Comment: @curfewed: It's usually a sign that undefined behavior is occurring somewhere else.

Comment: without enough information we can only do some guesswork and list all possible, that we can think of, problems, and probably we forget a bunch of it. waste of time. this is why there is some marvellous invention called debugger. so this is -1 like that. if you need help state your problem clearly and with enough information. and possibly do your own research first, don't be lazy.
at least what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

### You have a bug in your program. (This is the fish.)

This is the only reasonable response to your question as it is currently posed. A more targeted answer is only possible if you can narrow down which parts of your code changes its behavior when you add the `cout` expression, and present it. The process of narrowing down which parts of your program changes its behavior when you add the `cout` expression is a good start to ***debugging*** your program.

### Unfamiliar with *debugging*? (How to fish.)

Debugging is a forensic activity, in that you are trying to infer the reason the program does not behave in the way you expect it to behave. It combines logical reasoning and creative thinking. Being good at it is a highly desirable skill by employers of software engineers. Explaining all aspects of how to debug is beyond the scope of this answer, but since you are specifically confused about how `cout` expression could affect the behavior of your program, you should do the investigation to dispel your confusion.

You have to understand: *Adding a `cout` expression should not be able to change how your binary search works*. The fact that it does indicates, almost by definition, your program is invoking undefined behavior. You should take it as your mission to discover which part of your program is changing its behavior from adding the `cout` expression. Since you are asking what might be causing this behavior, it must be assumed you do not have a firm understanding of how to uncover this information for yourself. Below are tips to do so.

#### Design review: Understand how the program is supposed to work.

A design review is a critical analysis of how the program will fulfill its purpose. Sometimes a design review will reveal a logical flaw that leads to correcting a flaw in the implementation. Sometimes a design review will indicate possible weaknesses or corner cases that the implementation may have missed, and can help shed light on where to focus the spotlight when debugging the code itself. Understanding the design will help form a mental picture (or a model) of how the software is supposed to work if everything is implemented correctly.

#### Clean compilation: Enable all warnings, and treat warnings as errors.

When compiling your software, enable all the available warnings, and treat any reported warnings as errors. Understand each warning, and the best way to address it in the source code. This can help eliminate many obscure problems that would otherwise go unnoticed, and its benefits outweighs the false report (warnings on code that is actually not in error) that can sometime result. Less experience programmers will especially find it difficult to discern a true false report from a true bug, so it is better to just work to properly address all the warnings.

#### Code review: Understand what each line of code is supposed to do.

A code review is a critique of the software to make sure each line of code serves the intended purpose. Lines of code where the purpose is unclear are automatically suspect as possible sources of problems. A code review may also reveal lines of code that are clear, but clearly do not serve the intended purpose.

#### Code Instrumentation: Using assertions to validate assumptions and behavior model.

You can augment your software with `assert()` statements at critical points in the computation where you expect a condition to be true. For example, you might have the expectation that an index variable is within a certain range. You can design an assertion statement that will validate that expectation. If you encounter an assertion failure, it means at least one of your assumptions were invalid. Presumably (and you should validate that) all your assertions succeed with the `cout` expression in place. You want to take note of any assertions that fail when you remove the `cout` expression.

#### Code Test/Failure Reproduction: Use small test cases.

By using smaller input files (say, 10-20 lines) where the expected output is known, you can validate if your program is performing its intended function. If you can reproduce the "*with `cout` works, without doesn't work*" behavior with a smaller input set, it is easier to observe what might be going wrong with the program since the data to analyze is more focused around the problem itself.

#### Execution analysis: Use a debugger.

If you have a reproducible faulty test case, you can step through your programs execution using a debugger. You should understand exactly which lines of code will execute, which code paths should be taken, and what the expected values of the variables should be. The debugger can help you observe all this information while executing one line of code at a time.

#### Fault isolation: Finding the needle in the haystack.

Somewhere in the software, some logic of your program expresses different behavior depending on whether or not the `cout` expression is in place. Use the tools above to try to isolate what lines of code have this property, and try to identify the very first time a difference in behavior occurs. Then, look at what variables the code is depending upon to make a decision about how to behave. Based on the program model, and your understanding of how the code is supposed to work, you have to reason out what is causing variables to express themselves differently with the presence of the `cout` expression.

### Still stuck?

If you have reduced the problem to a few lines of code with a small test case, and you still do not understand the reason the behavior is not as you expect for those lines of code, you can then attempt to write up an explanation of the reduced problem as a question, and it will probably be well received here.